# query device model then look up settings?

Tags: android, configuration

Is there a framework or some standard approach to testing for device model and storing device specific settings?

For example, I may need to set camera’s `setDisplayOrientation(90)` on a Samsung Galaxy but `setDisplayOrientation(0)` on a Droid 3.  I need to store these per device settings and look them up based on device model.

I could implement this in `sqlite` but is there some standard Android approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For querying device details use
`Build.Model` and `Build.Manufacturer`.

If you want to store such device details I will suggest you to use `SharedPreferences` 
rather than `sqlite`.